# OSMDroid - Custom Marker moving as I zoom out

Tags: android, osmdroid

I have implemented OSMDroid and added a Custom Marker like this:

```
    mResourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
    mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mapController = this.mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(25);
    GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(DataManager.glat, DataManager.glon);
    mapController.setCenter(center);
    OverlayItem newItem = new OverlayItem("Here", "SampleDescription", center);
    Drawable newMarker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
    newItem.setMarker(newMarker);
```

This marker should be at the user´s location and the map should be centered there by default.
This works well, as long as I dont zoom:

[image: Original Zoom (25)]

But when I zoom out, the marker moves:
[image: Zoomed out a bit]

The distance increases with zoomlevel:
[image: Zoomed out even further]

Any idea what this is caused by? Are there any restrictions/guidelines for custom markers?

**Note:** This does NOT happen when using the default marker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem: `Hotspot`

Seems like the default `Hotspot` is `Bottom Center`, in my case, `Center` would be the right one. The bottom center of my marker WAS at the right place, it just didnt look like it.

`newItem.setMarkerHotspot(HotspotPlace.CENTER);` fixed it

This is basically my marker:

```
 ___________
|     _     |
|    ( )    |
|     V     |
|           |
|___________|
```